# How can I get my counter to work properly?

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm doing my c++ homework on arrays, everything seems to be working fine except the counter for the problem. Before I show the code these are the requirements for the question

1. create an array of 10 yes or no questions
2. prompt user to enter yes or no, yes being 'Y' or 'y'. anything else being no
3. Print back the number of yes'
4. Give a rank based on amount of yes'

This is what my code looks like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    //variables
    int i, yes;
    char choice;
    string mastery; 
    //declare array of questions
    string quiz [10] = {
    "1. Have you been gaming for more than three years? ", "2. Have you ever dressed as a videogame character for halloween? ", "3. Do you own more than one console? ", "4. Have you stayed up passed midnight to play games? ", "5. Have you ever thrown a controller out of rage? ", "6. Have you ever needed to look up a walk through for a game? ", "7. Do you have a main in a fighting game? ", "8. Ever watched an esports tournament? ", "9. Did you ever own a handheald console? ", "10. Ever had a crush on a character in a game? "
    };
    //header
  cout << "Are you truly a gamer? Take this quiz and find out!" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    //array 
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            cout << quiz[i];
            cin >> choice; 

            if (choice == 'Y' || choice == 'y')
            {
                yes = yes + 1;
            }
                
        }
    cout << endl;
    //amount of yes'
    cout << "You answered yes " << yes << " times" << endl;
    //calculate mastery level
    if (yes <=2)
    {
        mastery = "Novice";
    }
    else if (yes <= 5)
    {
        mastery = "Apprentice";
    }
    else if (yes <= 8)
    {
        mastery = "adept";
    }
    else if (yes <= 10)
    {
        mastery = "Expert";
    }    
    //print mastery level
    cout << "Your gamer rank is: " << mastery << endl;
}
```

This is a sample output I got

```
Are you truly a gamer? Take this quiz and find out!

1. Have you been gaming for more than three years? y
2. Have you ever dressed as a videogame character for halloween? y
3. Do you own more than one console? y
4. Have you stayed up passed midnight to play games? y
5. Have you ever thrown a controller out of rage? y
6. Have you ever needed to look up a walk through for a game? y
7. Do you have a main in a fighting game? y
8. Ever watched an esports tournament? y
9. Did you ever own a handheald console? y
10. Ever had a crush on a character in a game? y

You answered yes 4821545 times
Your gamer rank is:
```

I don't know why my counter is not working, would appreciate some feedback and solutions!

Comment: you did not set yes to 0 to start with

Comment: Your bug is here: `int i, yes;` local variables are not initialized to 0 unless you do that.

Answer (score 2):

The Fix:

```
int i = 0;
int yes = 0;
```

By default, C++ will not initialize your variables. Unless you do it explicitly, they will contain a garbage value.

Comment: Completely flew over my head, preciate it!